# Is it necessary to check all the field in equals method of model class in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

Is it necessary to check all the field in equals method of model class in JPA, or can I use only id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to put all of your fields in the equals method just because you're using JPA. In fact, JPA specific fields you *may* want to ignore.

You need to decide what makes most sense for your application, but it's quite common to exclude your @Id and @Version fields. Include only those fields that differentiate one instance of an object from another: essentially the fields that form the key.

Answer (score 2):

Not always. You should clearly see which fields form a native (business) key and compare only those fields. Sometimes all fields form the native key, sometimes not.

Read this discussion at hibernate forum about [strategies of implementing equals and hashcode](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/EqualsandHashCode).

Answer (score -1):

I would check the id only. In case it's null (not set), which is the case for just created objects, I would rely on standard equals implementation (comparison of references).